# Python performance comparison: Convert an Iterator to List and adding elements by index (after preallocating) vs Append while iterating

Tags: python, iterator, append

Long story short. What is better:

Given an iterator: eg. After Reading a CSV or getting query results from DB. What would give better performance and why?

First Approach: Iterate using the iterator and **append** to required lists. Something like:

```
element1_list=[]
element2_list=[]
for row in rows:
    element1_list.append(row[element1_index])
    element2_list.append(row[element2_index])
```

Second Approach: Convert the iterator to a list and access the elements after preallocation

```
row_list=list(rows)
length=len(row_list)
element1_list=[None]*length
element2_list=[None]*length
for i in range(0,length):
    element1_list[i]=row_list[i][element1_index]
    element2_list[i]=row_list[i][element2_index]
```

Preallocation has it's own benefits. But conversion to a list, may itself be an iteration itself. So what approach to choose and why? Would be interesting to know what happens under the hood?

**EDIT**: Again emphasizing, would like to know about the fundamental differences in these approaches. NOT merely using timeit and doing empirical analysis, which i would like to do to back up theory and not the other way around

Some of the performance criteria maybe:

1. Speed and CPU time
2. Memory

Comment: Is there some reason you need to separate the columns into discrete lists?

Comment: Third approach: `element1_list, element2_list = itertools.izip(*rows)`

Comment: I don't think there is an obviously better candidate.  Measure in your use cases if you care.  Probably doesn't change much.

Comment: if the lists are so small, that you keep them in memory, you will hardly see any difference

Comment: Also you may want to have a look at Python `timeit` module. It's part of the standard library. http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Comment: @cababunga Now timeit is something i wanted to avoid. I wanted to know the underlying procedure used in both cases and leave timeit as a last resort to validate theory and not the other way around

Comment: @aya : Make a plot between X and Y' (where these two are two different lists and Y' is obtained after some manipulation in list2)

Comment: They should have the same underlying big O performance, so `timeit` is pretty much the best thing you can have to go on.

Comment: @NipunBatra: Donald Knuth ([The Art of Computer Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming)) once said "premature optimization is the root of all evil". Even knowing the underlying implementation, performance results sometimes can be very counter-intuitive, so listen to cababunga and go profile your use case.

Comment: @PauloScardine  Result of timeit included in my answer. The results are very very different for the two methods

Comment: @NipunBatra As long as the "manipulation in list2" can calculate each Y' solely from its corresponding X and Y, there's no need to even load all the data into RAM at once, let alone split the data into two lists. Either way, the task assumes you already have two separate lists, so splitting one list into two would seem to be beyond the scope of the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since everyone recommends **timeit**, so here are the results and the accompanying code.[image: Results]

The code i used for testing is as follows:

```
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

index_element_1=0
index_element_2=2

def create_csv(num_records):
    '''Creates a test CSV'''
    a=open('test.csv','wb')
    a.write("10,20,30,40,50\n"*num_records)
    a.close()

def read_csv(filename):
    '''Returns iterator'''
    cr = csv.reader(open(filename,"rb"))
    return cr

def convert_to_list_method():
    global csv_iterator
    csv_list=list(csv_iterator)
    length_list=len(csv_list)
    x=[None]*length_list
    y=[None]*length_list
    for i in range(0,length_list):
        x[i]=csv_list[index_element_1]
        y[i]=csv_list[index_element_2]
    return [x,y]

def iterate_and_append_method():
    global csv_iterator
    x=[]
    y=[]
    for row in csv_iterator:
        x.append(row[index_element_1])
        y.append(row[index_element_2])
    return [x,y]


CSV_SIZE=range(10000,1010000,10000)
time_convert_to_list=[0]*len(CSV_SIZE)
time_iterate=[0]*len(CSV_SIZE)
count=0

for csv_size in CSV_SIZE:
    create_csv(csv_size)
    global csv_iterator
    csv_iterator=read_csv('test.csv')
    time_convert_to_list[count]=timeit.timeit("convert_to_list_method()", setup="from __main__ import *",number=1)
    csv_iterator=read_csv('test.csv')
    time_iterate[count]=timeit.timeit("iterate_and_append_method()", setup="from __main__ import *",number=1)
    count=count+1

plt.xlabel('CSV Size')
plt.ylabel('Time (s)')
plt.plot(CSV_SIZE,time_convert_to_list,label='Convert to List')
plt.plot(CSV_SIZE,time_iterate,label='Iterate')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The results don't vary much. I think all the comments were right. It does not really make a lot of difference.

NB: I used only 1 iteration of each function in timeit since o/w the iterator would have to be recreated, since it got consumed by previous iteration!